# Error: rootscope.infdig using ng-include with a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hy,

I made a header template, that I want to include on certain pages, using ng-include(being the only thing that came to my mind - if you have any other ideas as to how to include a header template to different pages without copying it, please suggest).

This is the code in the template:

```
<div ng-include="includeHeaderURL()"></div>
```

This is the code in the controller:

```
    $scope.template = [{
        'name': 'Header Template',
        'url': 'pages/authentication/header/template.html'
    }];
    $scope.includeHeaderURL = function () {
        return $scope.template[0].url;
    };
```

After running the page, Chrome freezes and I have an infinite loop of this error.

```
Error [$rootScope.infdig]
```

I tried adding the code in the template with:

```
 src="includeHeaderURL()"
```

I tried adding it with only the ng-include tag and the same errors occur.
I also added a hackish fix, with the:

```
$rootScopeProvider.digestTtl(15);
```

in the main config file, but then I get the error:

```
 Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

even though I add $rootScopeProvider.

Does anyone have any solutions or ideas?

Comment: make sure your path to the template is correct.

Comment: Yes, the path is correct.

Comment: I had a similar issue today, in case you're still interested in this problem:
- did you try printing the folder path + contents of the folder via javascript to double check the relative path is correct?
- can you provide the entire HTML for more context?
- were you using ASP.NET as backend by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

have you try this

```
<div ng-include="'pages/authentication/header/template.html'"></div>
```